# setting up rsync on a centOS on gcloud - error @ERROR: chdir failed

Tags: rsync, centos6, gcloud

I'm a complete noob in all gcloud
I was trying to setup an rsync module to have a sharecenter box do backup on a set schedule, which I was able to do on o centOS with digital ocean but somehow I can't get the same thing setup on a centOS vm instance in gcloud

here are my settings and all info I was able to gather about the issue I'm having

==================

my /etc/rsyncd.conf

motd file = /etc/rsyncd.motd

log file = /var/log/rsyncd.log

pid file = /var/run/rsyncd.pid

lock file = /var/run/rsync.lock

[moodleic]

path = /home/FranciscoCortes/backups

comment = backup module for moodle backup files folder defined in path

read only = no

list = yes

uid = nobody

gid = nobody

auth users = FranciscoCortes

secrets file = /etc/rsyncd.secrets

use chroot = no

hosts allow = *

==================

the path actualy exist

[FranciscoCortes@centos6 backups] cd /home/FranciscoCortes/backups/
[FranciscoCortes@centos6 backups]

================

the module exist

[FranciscoCortes@centos6 ~]$ rsync -va rsync://FranciscoCortes@localhost/

moodleic        backup module for moodle backup files folder defined in path

================

the permissions on the folder seem ok

[FranciscoCortes@centos6 ~]$ ls -l

total 8

drwxrwxr-x. 2 FranciscoCortes FranciscoCortes 4096 Jan  7 21:37 backups

================

sudo netstat -tulpn

tcp  0      0 :::873   :::*    LISTEN   17096/xinetd

================

cat /etc/services | grep rsync

rsync           873/tcp                         # rsync

rsync           873/udp                         # rsync

================

but the error I get is this

[FranciscoCortes@centos6 ~]$ rsync -va rsync://FranciscoCortes@localhost/moodleic/

Password: 
@ERROR: chdir failed
rsync error: error starting client-server protocol (code 5) at main.c(1503) [receiver=3.0.6]

================

the rsync error log shows this

2015/01/09 01:21:20 [16987] unable to bind any inbound sockets on port 873

2015/01/09 01:21:20 [16987] rsync error: error in socket IO (code 10) at socket.c(541) [receiver=3.0.6]

2015/01/09 01:25:37 [17118] connect from localhost (::1)

2015/01/09 01:25:48 [17118] rsync: chdir /home/FranciscoCortes/backups failed

: Permission denied (13)

================

I've tried to set the uid and gid the same as the user authorized on the secrets file which is already the owner of the folder in the path so I'm not sure why I would get the permission denied.

I'm I missing something??

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue? If yes, can you post the solution as an answer so that other users can benefit from it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think it could be caused by SELinux.

I'd set it to permissive and try a test run.

You can disable it temporarily with this command setenforce 0.

Sincerely,

Paolo